# Graphiql playground in a .Net Framework Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, graphql, graphiql, hotchocolate

How do we implement a Graphql Playground in ASP.NET Framework Web Application? I was able to query using Postman's new GraphQL POST and it is working as expected. But I was not able to host the graphiql playground using HotChocolate's AspNet Classic GraphiQL nuget.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HotChocolate.AspNetClassic.GraphiQL/

It would be really helpful if anyone can provide a code snippet or documentation specific to ASP.NET Framework.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/blob/master/examples/AspNetClassic.StarWars/Startup.cs) you fin example code. Does this help?

Comment: Url changed a bit.
https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/blob/master/examples/AspNetCore.StarWars/Startup.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is add it to your startup.cs file:

```
 //Graph QL add to pipeline and use schemas
 // app.UseWebSockets()
    app.UseGraphQL("/graphql")
       .UsePlayground();
```

You can also have it up automatically if you wanted to. Every time you hit debug, it will open the playground if you set the url in your project properties

[image]